# How to show GRUB menu instead of command line?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, grub2, uefi, ubiquity

I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a [Lenovo Ideapad 320](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-300-series/Ideapad-320-15-Intel/p/88IP3000842), but the installer always hangs at installing the `grub2` package. So I ran the installer with `ubiquity -b` (no bootloader) and it installs fine. I thought this way I could install grub manually.

When I boot, grub drops to the `grub>` command line prompt. I can boot using the following commands:

```
set root=hd0,msdos5
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

I tried getting a normal grub menu in many ways, but none seem to work. I ran `grub-install /dev/sda`, `grub-update`, I tried modifying the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file, etc. But I keep getting the `grub>` prompt. How do I get the menu?

Edit: This is what `/etc/default/grub` looks like:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: If Secure Boot and Fast Boot are enabled in the BIOS/Firmware setup, please disable them for the installation process.

Comment: What modifying have you done with the configure file? @K7AAY What's the matter with Secure Boot? Grub already worked, it wasn't refused by UEFI firmware, it's just the menu timeout was set to 0, so no menu can be shown

Comment: Nah, I did set the timeout, see edit.

Comment: I'll check out fast boot and secure boot.